# Will I have problem with PHP 5.5 and WordPress 4.9.4?

Tags: php, compatibility

I made a fresh installation of the newest version of the WordPress in `Ubuntu Server 14.04` where the PHP version is `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 (cli) (built: Aug 4 2017 19:40:28)`

I managed to install the WordPress site and a purchased theme successfully till now.

Will I encounter any problem with the site development?

I am asking because later I noticed this in [WordPress requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)..

> PHP version 7.2 or greater

Comment: It is written there: not required, but recommended. And below you can see that WordPress can work with  PHP 5.2.4+

Comment: PHP 5.5 is end-of-life and may leave you [exposed to unpatched security vulnerabilities](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). Upgrade or change host. Not being able to use a newer version is worth changing host over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not face any problem because of `PHP 5.5`. *WordPress recommends (not required or mandatory) `PHP 7.2` because it has better performance than the older versions.* If you need better performance than `PHP 5.5` then you should definitely use `PHP 7.2`. Btw, WordPress even smoothly works with `PHP 5.2.4`!.

Comment: Vastly more important that performance improvements is that PHP 5.5 is end-of-life, and may leave you exposed to unpatched security vulnerabilities.